# How to use nginx reverse_proxy for PUT requests?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-method

When I use nginx as reverse proxy in front of some other web application, it seems not to forward `PUT` requests, but shows an HTTP 405 generated by nginx (and not the upstream server).

I tried the `proxy_next_upstream` method for http_405, but it did not work. I wonder why nginx itself checks the HTTP method anyway for a location block which has a reverse_proxy configured.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx is not the problem here. It forwards `PUT` requests in reverse proxy blocks as expected, if the `location` matches the request.

I had another `location` directive, which makes sure images are not served via the reverse proxy. It matched everything with `.png` (and some other file extensions) in the end, which matched the upload-urls as well.

For the wrong location block, the error 405 is correct. The solution is to make sure the upload requests are actually forwarded into the reverse proxy.

---

An example for a working reverse proxy configuration:

```
# proxy requests for /upload the a webapp, which implements PUT
location ^~ /upload {
    proxy_pass "https://backendserver:1234/something";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering off;
    tcp_nodelay on;
}
```

The configuration works fine, if there are no other location blocks, which take precedence.
My problem was another block:

```
# This block matched requests for /upload/somefile.png before the proxy block
location ~* ^(/.*png|/.*jpg|/.*jpeg|/.*gif)$ {
    # some directives without proxy_pass
}
```

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: I added an example, but it is pretty much from default configurations and documentation. The important point is to make sure which location block processes the request.